# Error when adding dynamic an ImageCombo control to a userform in vba excel by programming

Tags: excel, vba

This code does not work ...why?

```
Set fmSubComp = fmFrameSection.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1") 'This code work
Set fmSubComp = fmFrameSection.Controls.Add("Forms.ImageCombo.1") 'This code does not work ...why?
```

I get this error

> Run time error '-2147221005(800401f3)': Invalid class string

Comment: [Some Reading Here That Will Help I Think](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-microsoft-forms). Not which ones are on the list and which ones aren't on the list.

Answer (score 0):

**I have already solved it.**

You have to check the classes of the control members (known as ProgID) in VBA Excel.

To review the member classes, we open the regedit> click on the edit> tab and select search and enter the library (the .dll or other object reference) from which we want to know the member classes of the controls that we will use. Or we simply go to the address:

Team \ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Classes \ MSComctlLib.ImageComboCtl

**Note:** the "MSComctlLib.ImageComboCtl" is the class that cannot be resolved in my case.